# Is there a constant $K$ s.t. $|\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}|^2\leq K|x-y|$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

I try to answer the following question:
Assume $x,y \in [0,1]$. Does a constant
$K\in \mathbb{R}$ exists s.t.

$|\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}|^2\leq K|x-y|$

First note that it holds $|\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}|^2\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

The first argument would be to assume $|x-y|\geq\frac{1}{4}$
Then the following inequalities hold:

$|\sqrt{x(1-x)}-\sqrt{y(1-y)}|^2<4*\frac{1}{4}\leq 4*|x-y|$

The case $|x-y|<\frac{1}{4}$ is more demanding. If we find in this case a second constant $K_1$, we can choose $max(4,K_1)=K$ and proved the inequality.

I tried already my limited methods for proving it or produce a counterexample. I have the feeling it is somehow possible to show that such K exists. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Would not $x=y=0$ constitute a counterexample..?

Comment: 1928 song  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6HpgGsvCPM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is essentially asking if $f(x)=\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is $\frac 12$-Holder continuous (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition). Similar to in the animation on this Wikipedia page on Lipschitz continuity (a.k.a. $1$-Holder continuous) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity, this is equivalent to saying that there is some constant $C>0$ s.t. the graph of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ lies between $C|x-a|^{1/2} + f(a)$ and $-C|x-a|^{1/2} + f(a)$ for all $a\in [0,1]$.

Of course, the first thing one should do when trying a question like this is to graph it on e.g. Desmos:
[image]
and it looks like $f(x)$ is indeed $\frac 12$-Holder continuous with constant $1$. With this numerical/visual evidence, I do not think it will be hard to rigorously show the claim.

Comment: Thanks for this connection to Holder-continuity, didn't see that. Can you specify where the constant $C$ comes in to play in your description. If I understood you right, it is enough to show that: for $x\in[0,1]$ it holds that $\forall a\in [0,1]: -|x-a|^{\frac{1}{2}}+f(a) \leq f(x)\leq +|x-a|^{\frac{1}{2}}+f(a)$

Comment: I have added the $C$. Yes, that's right.